# ANDROID: Creating a button that needs to be pushed for X seconds

Tags: java, android, button

What I am looking for is to have a button where:

If you just push it, does nothing.

If you push and hold it for, let's say, 3 seconds, perform an action().

Any idea of what to do?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: doesn't onLongClickListener solve your problem,if X seconds is not that important for you?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to be able to specify the time, here is an implementation of `OnTouchListener` that does that for you, **without** using a `Timer`:

```
class TimedTouchListener implements OnTouchListener{
    private final long millisRequired = 3000;
    private long downTime;

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event){
        switch(event.getAction()){
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            downTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            return true;
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            long upTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            if( upTime - downTime > millisRequired ){
                doAction(); //doAction can be a method call, or any code you want to be executed.
                return true;
            }else{
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

If you don't need to specify the time, just go with an `OnLongClickListener` as suggested by others.

Answer (score 4):

```
button.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
        // remeber here that ACTION_DOWN has occured
        // set the timer for 3 seconds
        // if ACTION_UP occured and timer has elapsed, then call action().
    }});
```

or as ntc noticed, you can use OnLongClickListener instead.

Answer (score 3):

Thats what the LongClickListener is for:  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnLongClickListener.html

Comment: Not exactly what I was looking for, as I am asked to have a specified ammount of time being pushed, but thank you very much, nice answer

Answer (score 0):

on finger down start a 3 second timer.
on finger up if timer is still active cancel it.
on timer expire run action.